# .cshrc quoting in complex alias

Tags: linux, tcsh

The following line works in tcsh shell when entered directly:

```
df -P . | awk -F: 'NR==2 {print "//"$1}' | awk '{printf "%s/%s\n", $0, ENVIRON["PWD"]}' | awk '{gsub("/home/", ""); gsub("/", "\\"); print}'
```

But when I try to use in in .cshrc to create an alias:

```
alias foo " df -P . | awk -F: 'NR==2 {print "//"$1}' | awk '{printf "%s/%s\n", $0, ENVIRON["PWD"]}' | awk '{gsub("/home/", ""); gsub("/", "\\"); print}' "
```

the outermost double quotes seem to be breaking things:

```
> foo
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %s/%sn, /usr/bin/tcsh, ENVIRON[PWD]}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/home/, ); gsub(/, \); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/home/, ); gsub(/, \); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:               ^ 0 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub
```

I have tried multiple combinations of quotes ([following info here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch27_13.htm#:%7E:text=27.13.2.%20How%20Quoting%20Works)) with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use an alias, use a shell script. Then you can write it in better scripting language like `bash`.

Comment: At the very least, make it a function, not an alias. I assume csh supports them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this quoting abomination:

```
alias foo "df -P . | awk -F: 'NR==2 {print "\$"1}'| awk '{printf "\""//%s/%s\n"\"", "\$"0, ENVIRON["\""PWD"\""]}' | awk '{gsub("\""/home/"\"", "\"""\""); gsub("\""/"\"", "\""\\"\""); print}' "
```

The key was to replace:

```
$ -> "\$" 
within single-quoted awk: " -> "\""
```